# Trancsode and generate waveform data file in ffmpeg with a single command

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to transcode and generate a waveform data file in the same command. I cannot figure out how to generate 2 output files from a single input. I want an mp4 file, and the waveform data file. The waveform data needs to be generated from the output of the transcoding step (ie, after the stream has already been transcoded)

The following does not work:

```
ffmpeg -i "https://mp3l.jamendo.com/?trackid=862797&format=mp31" -map 0:a -c:a libfdk_aac out1.mp4 -f data data.txt
Output file #1 does not contain any stream
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the tee muxer, you can write to multiple outputs. See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs#Duplicateoutputs

```
ffmpeg -i "https://mp3l.jamendo.com/?trackid=862797&format=mp31" -c:a libfdk_aac -f tee -map 0:a "output.mp4|[f=data]output.txt"
```

Comment: Your data output isn't the waveform data for the encoded stream. It is a raw binary dump of the coded packets. The encoded stream has to be decoded in order to generate its PCM representation. That has to happen in a separate command.You can map the encoded stream to a separate tee output (format adts) and pipe that to another ffmpeg process which decodes to PCM and saves to file.